# Ranking with Duplicates

Tags: oracle

I am using Oracle Apex and I am ranking call speed. I am almost getting the results I am after.  The only issue that I have faced is that when the rank function comes across duplicate values, by default they both get assigned the lowest Rank. e.g.

```
Rank  Call Speed
1             65
2             72
3             92
4            102
4            102
4            102
4            102
4            102
9            113
10           154
11           201
12           352
```

Is there anyway to have the 4's represent as 8's (the highest rank of the duplicates)

One way of doing this is by using the ranking Descending and then subtracting this from the highest rank + 1.  this works but seems like an unnecessary step.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: When ranking isn't 1 generally considered the highest? It's conventional to award the higher rank to tied values in the real world. Do you really want them all as 8, or as 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 - assigned semi-randomly if you have no way to break the tie? (Including your existing query and sample data, as text rather than images, would generally be helpful. An image is much harder to use to recreate your issue).

Comment: I can see where you are coming from but In a contact centre environment we dont want to tell a group of 5 people with the same Handling Time that person a was ranked higher than person b, c, d, e.  We want to reflect that they were equals, however we want them to have the higher outcome.

Comment: OK, so not `dense_rank` then, just checking. Why is it better to say they're all 8th though, rather than all 4th? Just curious...

Comment: Rank 4 means "there were only 3 others faster than you".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of a strange thing to do, but I would do something like:

```
with data as (
    select 65 call_speed from dual union all
    select 72 call_speed from dual union all
    select 92 call_speed from dual union all
    select 102 call_speed from dual connect by level <= 5 union all
    select 113 call_speed from dual union all
    select 154 call_speed from dual union all
    select 201 call_speed from dual union all
    select 352 call_speed from dual
)
select
    rank() over (order by call_speed) + count(*) over (partition by call_speed) - 1 rank,
    call_speed
from data;
```

Which gives you:

```
      RANK CALL_SPEED
---------- ----------
         1         65
         2         72
         3         92
         8        102
         8        102
         8        102
         8        102
         8        102
         9        113
        10        154
        11        201
        12        352
```

Answer (score 2):

Just an alternative, for no reason at all, except maybe to avoid any memory overhead (?) from doing a partitioned count:

```
with data as (
    select 65 call_speed from dual union all
    select 72 call_speed from dual union all
    select 92 call_speed from dual union all
    select 102 call_speed from dual connect by level <= 5 union all
    select 113 call_speed from dual union all
    select 154 call_speed from dual union all
    select 201 call_speed from dual union all
    select 352 call_speed from dual
)
select
    count(*) over () + 1 - rank() over (order by call_speed desc) rank,
    call_speed
from data
order by call_speed;
```